# Variable becomes undefined after npm run production in Vue + Laravel project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, npm

I have a variable **var self = this** that becomes **var self = undefined** after npm run production.

For context, this is a Laravel project that I am adding Vue to create a Homepage.vue component.

First I created the assets/js/homepage/homepage.js:

```
// *****************************
// ***** Private Variables *****
// *****************************
/**
 * Save this instance
 * @type @this;
 * @private
 */
 var self = this;

 /**
  * If Module has been initiated
  * @type Boolean
  * @private
  */
 var _isInit = false; // to avoid 'rebinds'

 /**
  * Categories Component instance
  */
 const homepage = require('./components/homepage');


 // ****************************
 // ***** Public functions *****
 // ****************************
 /**
  * start
  *
  * Starts the module
  * Inits private variables and executes specific logic needed for the module
  * to start.
  *
  * @public
  */
 this.start = function() {
     if(!_isInit) {
         console.log("Homepage starts..");

         homepage.start();
     }
 };

 self.start();
```

Then, I created the assets/js/homepage/component/homepage.js file:

```
// *****************************
// ***** Private Variables *****
// *****************************
/**
 * Save this instance
 * @type @this;
 * @private
 */
 var self = this;

 /**
  * If Module has been initiated
  * @type Boolean
  * @private
  */
 var _isInit = false; // to avoid 'rebinds'

 /**
  * Request
  * @type String
  * @private
  */
 var _request;

 /**
  * Forms Instance
  */
 import Homepage from './Homepage.vue';

 // *****************************
 // ***** Private functions *****
 // *****************************
 /**
  *
  * Forms
  *
  * Create Forms
  *
  */
 var _homepage = function () {
     // Create all requested instances
     new Vue({
         el: '#homepage',
         mixins: [Homepage],
     });
 };

 // ****************************
 // ***** Public functions *****
 // ****************************
 /**
  * start
  *
  * Starts the module
  * Inits private variables and executes specific logic needed for the module
  * to start.
  *
  * @required
  * @param request
  * @type array
  *
  * @public
  */

 self.start = function() {
     if(!_isInit) {
         // Init Forms Component
         _homepage();
     }
 };
```

Then I added to laravel mix the script file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('resources/assets/js/homepage/homepage.js', 'public/js/homepage');
```

After running npm run production the file **public/js/homepage/homepage.js** is created.

I will paste the part of the code that is creating errors in the console:

```
// ***** Private Variables *****
// *****************************

var self = undefined;

var _isInit = false; 

var _homepage = function _homepage() {
  // Create all requested instances
  new Vue({
    el: '#homepage',
    mixins: [_Homepage_vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["default"]]
  });
};
```

The code above generates the following error and the component is not mounted:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'start' of undefined
at Module../resources/assets/js/homepage/components/homepage.js (homepage.js:12936)
at webpack_require (homepage.js:20)
at Object../resources/assets/js/homepage/homepage.js (homepage.js:12974)
at webpack_require (homepage.js:20)
at Object.1 (homepage.js:13007)
at webpack_require (homepage.js:20)
at homepage.js:84
at homepage.js:87

If I manually replace the **var self = undefined;** to **var self=this** in the **public/js/homepage/homepage.js** file there are no errors, the component gets mounted and everything is fixed. The problem is that I have to make this correction everytime after npm run watch. I just don´t understand why this is happening.

EDIT: If I remove the var self = this the same error occurs, now "this" becames undefined:

```
undefined.start = function () {
  if (!_isInit) {
    // Init Forms Component
    _homepage();
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought `this` WAS undefined at the top level of modules (hint: I'm usually right)

Comment: just don't put `var self = this;` at all, `self` will be the global object (`window` in a web page) without you needing to set it - I guess it depends on what you expect `this` (and by extension, `self`) to actually BE

Comment: by the way .... *I will paste the part of the code that is creating errors in the console:* ... no errors there, as `self` is never referenced in that code

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed the var self = this and what happens after that is the same error because now "this" becames undefined. I will edit the question with that information.